# how to group by only specific features using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

I have this data frame

```
+---------+------+-----+-------------+-----+
|    LCLid|KWH/hh|Acorn|Acorn_grouped|Month|
+---------+------+-----+-------------+-----+
|MAC000002|   0.0|    0|            0|   10|
|MAC000002|   0.0|    0|            0|   10|
|MAC000002|   0.0|    0|            0|   10|
```

I want to group by the LCid and month's average consumption only in a certain way that a get

```
+---------+-----+------------------+----------+------------------+
|    LCLid|Month|       sum(KWH/hh)|Acorn     |Acorn_grouped     |
+---------+-----+------------------+----------+------------------+
|MAC000003|   10| 904.9270009999999|      0   |              0   | 
|MAC000022|    2|1672.5559999999978|      1   |              0   |
|MAC000019|    4| 368.4720001000007|      1   |              1   |
|MAC000022|    9|449.07699989999975|      0   |              1   |
|MAC000024|    8| 481.7160003000004|      1   |              0   |
```

but what I could do is using this code

```
dataset=dataset.groupBy("LCLid","Month").sum()
```

which gave me this result

```
+---------+-----+------------------+----------+------------------+----------+
|    LCLid|Month|       sum(KWH/hh)|sum(Acorn)|sum(Acorn_grouped)|sum(Month)|
+---------+-----+------------------+----------+------------------+----------+
|MAC000003|   10| 904.9270009999999|      2978|              2978|     29780|
|MAC000022|    2|1672.5559999999978|     12090|              4030|      8060|
|MAC000019|    4| 368.4720001000007|     20174|              2882|     11528|
|MAC000022|    9|449.07699989999975|      8646|              2882|     25938|
```

the problem is that the sum function was calculated also on the acron and acron_grouped
have you any idea how could I make the grouping only on the KWH/hh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you want to handle the other two columns. If you don't want to sum them, and just want any value from that column, you can do

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

dataset = dataset.groupBy("LCLid","Month").agg(
    F.sum("KWH/hh"),
    F.first("Acorn").alias("Acorn"),
    F.first("Acorn_grouped").alias("Acorn_grouped")
)
```

Comment: the other columns should remain the same since for every LCLid have it's fixed acron and Acorn_grouped number

Comment: @eyabaklouti then you can also try `dataset = dataset.groupBy("LCLid","Month","Acorn","Acorn_grouped").agg(F.sum("KWH/hh"))`